# On BeagleBone Black QtGui application doesn't open GUI window, instead runs in terminal

Tags: qt, qtgui, beagleboneblack

I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1
Based on Qt 4.8.0 (32 bit)
Built on Mar 21 2012
installed on virtual box with Ubuntu.
I have BeagleBone Black of Revision A5B. i have apt get qt4-embedded on it.

I have created a QtGui application and copied the same into my BeagleBone.
I executed the project by:
./ -qws
it gives qDebug string output on the terminal, but the GUI is not there on screen, i have attached this to my HDMI TV, where i see the terminal with output but no GUI.

Do i need to add some stuff to beaglebone black?
Some files nned to be copied to board?

Comment: is your app running with gui on desktop (have 'CONFIG+= core gui' in .pro)? Does the beaglebone have QtGui4.so? Eventually you can provide missing libraries.

Comment: Yes when i compile it for desktop, it works fine on my desktop.

Comment: I have done: 
opkg update
opkg install qt4-embedded -depends

Comment: I think i have      QT += core gui          in my .pro file, the default one

Comment: check if your qt4-embeded includes QtGui4.so. Eventually the qt4 package is split into several packages for your distribution (qt4-embeded may just be QtCore4.so)? The other posibillity is to provide Qt libraries on your own.

Comment: I am a newbie to this, may i know where to look for QtGui4. For manual file copy which files do i need to copy from which target folder in my desktop to which location on beaglebone black.

Thanks in Advance
Sahil